# PHP going down with ids

Tags: php, html, attributes

[image]

I have a table with a button in each line. Each line has its own specific id. Is there a function in PHP that allows me to specify exactly which button is pressed? I mean when I click first button it should notify me that it was a button within a line with id='1', etc.

@edit

```
function usunKontakt() {
    var temp = $(this).parent().parent().children(":first-child").text();
    console.log("Javascript: "+temp);
}
$("button.usun").click(usunKontakt);
```

That's exactly what I want to do in PHP, what I made in jQuery. Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: use link instead of buttons...

Comment: Well, for a start you can have a `onclick` function, which passes the id to the corresponding js funtion, Like `onclick="myFunction('1')"` on the 1st element.

Comment: don't use an inline click handler

Answer (score 0):

OK  you have a couple problems with your concept.

**First** 
PHP is a server side language, which means that it's functions occur a long before the button is actually pressed.

**Second** the 'id' attribute is used as the Elements identifier, so it's should be unique and should NOT be a number or either start with a number. 
I strongly recommend you to read this post: [naming convetions for html's ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028211/what-is-the-standard-naming-convention-for-html-css-ids-and-classes) 
and this: 
[valid id attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Now, when you say that '*me*' at:

> *when I click first button it should notify me*

You refer me => as User

OR

me => as Server?

If you edit your question to be more specific, it would be easier to help you)

Comment: I know that naming was a bit inappropriate. I know how to do it in Javascript. What i meant was for example when i Click button it should print on a page its id. When someone mentioned here in Javascript I can use parent method and then find its attribute id, but is there something similar in PHP?

Comment: Like I said, PHP is a server side language, so *NO, you don't handle click with PHP*. For that you should use Javascript and there are many different ways to do that. If you need to notify your server after the click, you can just send a request, for example HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).parent().siblings().filter(':first').html());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <button>test</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button>test</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>
      <button>test</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Depends on your table structure, but you could search for the first TD of each TR and catch its html contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery inside a button function

```
$(this).parents(".parent-id/class").find(".content id/class ").show();
```

// PHP

// use different names for each buttons

```
if(isset($_POST['buttonname']))
{

function;
}
```